# Extending TypographyProps and TextFieldProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am making a React component with TypeScript and Material UI (MUI).

It's a component which renders an input or a text.

You use the prop `mode` to switch between them,

If you set the `mode` prop to `view` it's going to render the text.

If you set the `mode` prop to `edit` it's going to render the input.

Here's the code:

```
import { Typography, TextField } from '@mui/material'
import type { TypographyProps, TextFieldProps } from '@mui/material'

interface InputComponentProps {
  mode: 'edit' | 'view'
  content?: string
}

type EditModeProps = TextFieldProps & {
  mode: 'edit'
} & InputComponentProps

interface ViewModeProps extends TypographyProps, InputComponentProps {
  mode: 'view'
}

export default function InputComponent(props: EditModeProps | ViewModeProps) {
  const { mode, content, ...compProps } = props
  if (mode === 'edit') return <TextField value={content} {...(compProps as EditModeProps)} />
  if (mode === 'view') return <Typography children={content} {...(compProps as ViewModeProps)} />
}
```

TypeScript is not complaining. However, now when I consume this component, I am having a problem in the outside.

I can use it as the following normally, no problems:

```
<InputComponent mode="edit" />
<InputComponent mode="view" />
```

however, I can't do the following:

```
import InputComponent from './InputComponent'

interface UserProfilePageProps {
  mode: 'edit' | 'view'
}

export default function UserProfilePage(props: UserProfilePageProps) {
  const { mode } = props
  // the following works
  /* return <InputComponent mode={'view'} content="hello world" /> */
  /* return <InputComponent mode={'edit'} content="hello world" /> */
  // the following works but its showing a compile time error?
  return <InputComponent mode={mode} content="hello world" />
}
```

Now TypeScript is saying:

```
Type '{ mode: "edit" | "view"; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & (EditModeProps | ViewModeProps)'.
  Type '{ mode: "edit" | "view"; }' is not assignable to type 'ViewModeProps'.
    Types of property 'mode' are incompatible.
      Type '"edit" | "view"' is not assignable to type '"view"'.
        Type '"edit"' is not assignable to type '"view"'.
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-bohr-kejjod?file=/src/UserProfilePage.tsx)

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript tries to match the props you are passing to `InputComponent` to both `EditProps` and `ViewProps`, and since the `mode` of `UserProfilePageProps` can be both `edit` or `view`, there is an ambiguity. This is how union types work.

You'll have to tell explicitly TypeScript which part of the union the props are by setting `mode="view"` or `mode="edit"` explicitly. Another way can be by telling to skip matching at all, i.e. `<InputComponent {...({ mode, content: 'hello world' } as Parameters<typeof InputComponent>[0])} />`.